# How to add a text speech in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I have this function that blits text to the screen:

```
def text_speech(font : str ,size : int,text : str,color,x,y, bold : bool):
    SCREEN = width, height = 900, 600
    font = pygame.font.Font(font,size)
    font.set_bold(bold)
    text = font.render(text, True, color)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = (x,y)
    screen.blit(text,textRect)
```

If I have

```
screen.fill((0,0,0))
text_speech('arialnarrow.ttf', 30, 'Hello', (255,255,255),  
            width/2, height/2, False)
```

It prints 'Hello' on a black screen with white text. If the player hovers over this text, how can I make a text bubble appear that looks like this:

[image: this]

I just want a text that has a green background and says 'Click to Confirm'. Anyone got any clue of to how to do this. I apologize, I'm a bit new to Pygame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 4th parameter of `font.render` is the optional background color of the text:

```py
color = (255, 255, 255)
background = (0, 255, 0)
text = font.render(text, True, color, background)
```

---

Another option is to render the text to a surface and to convert the surface format to a per pixel alpha format (`convert_alpha`):

```py
textSurf = font.render(text, True, color).convert_alpha()
textSize = textSurf.get_size()
```

Create a new surface with the double size:

```py
bubbleSurf = pygame.Surface((textSize[0]*2., textSize[1]*2))
bubbleRect = bubbleSurf.get_rect()
```

Fill the surface with the background color of the bubble:

```py
bubbleSurf.fill(background)
```

Blit the text onto the bubble surface:

```py
bubbleSurf.blit(textSurf, textSurf.get_rect(center = bubbleRect.center))
```

Blit the bubble surface onto `screen`:

```py
bubbleRect.center = (x,y)
screen.blit(bubbleSurf, bubbleRect)
```

Full function `text_speech`:

```py
def text_speech(font : str ,size : int,text : str,color,background,x,y, bold : bool):
    SCREEN = width, height = 900, 600
    font = pygame.font.Font(font,size)
    font.set_bold(bold)
    textSurf = font.render(text, True, color).convert_alpha()
    textSize = textSurf.get_size()   
    bubbleSurf = pygame.Surface((textSize[0]*2., textSize[1]*2))
    bubbleRect = bubbleSurf.get_rect()
    bubbleSurf.fill(background)
    bubbleSurf.blit(textSurf, textSurf.get_rect(center = bubbleRect.center))
    bubbleRect.center = (x,y)
    screen.blit(bubbleSurf, bubbleRect)
```

```py
text_speech('arialnarrow.ttf', 30, 'Hello', (255,255,255), (0,128,0), 
            width/2, height/2, False)
```

---

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import pygame.font

pygame.init()

width, height = 400, 300
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
textRect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)

def text_speech(font : str, size : int, text : str,color,background,x,y, bold : bool, bubble: bool):
    global textRect
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40) 
    #font = pygame.font.Font(font,size)
    font.set_bold(bold)
    textSurf = font.render(text, True, color).convert_alpha()
    if bubble:
        textSize = textSurf.get_size()   
        bubbleSurf = pygame.Surface((textSize[0]*2., textSize[1]*2))
        textRect = bubbleSurf.get_rect()
        bubbleSurf.fill(background)
        bubbleSurf.blit(textSurf, textSurf.get_rect(center = textRect.center))
        textRect.center = (x,y)
        screen.blit(bubbleSurf, textRect)
    else:
        textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
        textRect.center = (x,y)
        screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    hover = textRect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    text_speech('arialnarrow.ttf', 30, 'Hello', (255,255,255), (0, 128, 0), 
        (width/2), (height/2), False, hover)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: How do I make that 4th parameter appear when hovered over said text?

Comment: @AK-10CA-GlenforestSS2172 Thank you. Anyway I've add an example.